# Python: Configuring Tkinter widget with argument to configure as a string

Tags: python, string, tkinter, configure

I'm using Python and Tkinter and was wondering whether there is anyway I could do something like this because currently it gives me an error. I would like to be able to configure a widget with user input as a string to decide what to configure, hence why the variable `'string_variable'` needs to be a string.

```
tk_widget.config(string_variable = variable)
```

At the moment, I get an error saying `"TclError: unknown option -'string_of_stringvar_here'"` Please help me! Thank you for your replies in advance.
 - Ed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can treat a widget like a dictionary, with attributes being keys. For example:

```
label = tk.Label(root)
...
some_attribute = "background"
some_value = "red"
label[some_attribute] = some_value
```

You can also build up a dictionary of attributes and values, and pass that to the `config` method:

```
values = {some_attribute: some_value}
label.config(values)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. All sorted now!!